# HTTP 6369: SOCKET ERROR: read ECONNRESET - Node server connecting to Filemaker Data API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, filemaker

I have run into this error with my Node server when trying to access a Filemaker Server driven backend both locally and remotely.

`HTTP 6369: SOCKET ERROR: read ECONNRESET Error: read ECONNRESET at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)`

After trying everything I can find, triple-checking my FMS settings and logs, restarting the server and the machine several times, I cannot figure out what exactly is going wrong and how to solve it.

I have seen some answers to similar questions here on SO, but for the most part they just suggest catching the error in the express route (has not been changed for months and was working fine before the error), which I have done but it just outputs a more verbose version of the main error above:

```
HTTP 6369: SOCKET ERROR: read ECONNRESET Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:838:35)
    at tickOnSocket (_http_client.js:691:10)
    at onSocketNT (_http_client.js:744:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
    at ClientRequest.onSocket (_http_client.js:732:11)
    at setRequestSocket (_http_agent.js:436:7)
    at handleSocketCreation_Inner (_http_agent.js:429:7)
    at oncreate (_http_agent.js:286:5)
    at Agent.createSocket (_http_agent.js:291:5)
    at Agent.addRequest (_http_agent.js:248:10)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:296:16)
    at Object.request (https.js:314:10)
    at Request.start (/Users/******/Documents/*****/code/******/node_modules/request/request.js:751:32)
THE ERR :  Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:838:35)
    at tickOnSocket (_http_client.js:691:10)
    at onSocketNT (_http_client.js:744:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
---------------------------------------------
    at ClientRequest.onSocket (_http_client.js:732:11)
    at setRequestSocket (_http_agent.js:436:7)
    at handleSocketCreation_Inner (_http_agent.js:429:7)
    at oncreate (_http_agent.js:286:5)
    at Agent.createSocket (_http_agent.js:291:5)
    at Agent.addRequest (_http_agent.js:248:10)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:296:16)
    at Object.request (https.js:314:10)
    at Request.start (/Users/********/Documents/*******/code/******/node_modules/request/request.js:751:32) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall:'read'
}
```

Also, my Node API in general had already been operating more or less seamlessly for several months of development before this problem arose. One thing was that changed on my machine was my company adding [ScaleFusion](https://scalefusion.com/?campaignid=1706311350&adgroupid=69473391307&adid=416559737915&utm_medium=ppc&utm_term=%2Bscalefusion&utm_source=adwords&utm_campaign=Search-NA-Brand&hsa_kw=%2Bscalefusion&hsa_acc=6773144759&hsa_ad=416559737915&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_src=g&hsa_tgt=kwd-671454312385&hsa_grp=69473391307&hsa_mt=b&hsa_cam=1706311350&hsa_ver=3) device management software. I mentioned before the install that it could cause problems with the Node server API calls and the error only happened after ScaleFusion was added. Maybe it is possible the software is causing this problem?

Have been trying to find a fix for a couple of days now but running out of leads on it. If anyone can help out I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you ruled out Data API problems, can you connect to the DATA API otherwise? E.g. can you use Postman to get an authentication key?

Comment: Yes, I also checked using Postman and receive the same error. I forgot to mention that, thanks!

Comment: Does the server have a valid SSL certificate installed and are you connecting with the same FQDN as the certificate?

Comment: I just checked my local Filemaker server SSL configuration and the expiry date is February 2050. We are using the Claris test certificate as we are still in development. Regarding the FQDN, I am not sure how to check that is/is still correct though. The administrator of the server itself handled that side of things. The strange thing is that however it was set up worked for months without issue and nothing I know of has 
been  changed on the FM server that could cause such an error. Thanks for response. It has helped open up a new lead for debugging.

Comment: Yes the first step will be to get a valid authentication key from postman or similar. There is some example PHP to get an authentication key here also if you want to test that way: https://schwarzsoftware.com.au/blogentry.php?id=19

Comment: Also I am not sure if the FileMaker DATA API works with the default FileMaker certificate. If you set postman to ignore SSL errors it might? A cheap SSL certificate would fix this up.

Comment: The FileMaker DATA API works perfectly fine with the Claris Test Certificate when connecting locally on the same machine at least. I have no problem with this or the actual DATA API itself. As I mentioned above, I already have a working app that was previously connecting to my FMS DB without any major issues, logging in, receiving tokens, and making data requests. The ECONNRESET error just popped up out of the blue for no apparent reason a few days ago and I haven't been able to find a solution or even a clear reason for it.